# CakePHP Routing Alias, no prefix

Tags: cakephp

I have a dashboard with a series of widgets. Per specification, the widgets need to be buried under a /widgets/ directory.

So I have added the following to my routes.php

```
Router::connect('/widget/:controller/:action/*', array());
```

But I seem to be running into trouble on widget/links/ and widget/links/view/1

I am new to CakePHP, but this doesn't seem all that impressive. I have yet to find anything in the Book or by search. So any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to work here on v1.2.7 (ie. `/widget/links/view/70` goes to `LinksController::view(70)`)

Comment: I'd be tempted to make a Widgets plugin, then the routing would take care of it's self. `array('plugin'=>'widgets','controller'=>'widgets','action'=>'weather')` kinda thing :)

Comment: I am running 1.3, but the full URLs do indeed work. It is the index action that is the problem, when access via `/widget/links/`.

I don't think I want a Widgets plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...at the risk of stating the obvious...your route starts with `/widget/`, but you indicate that you're trying to access it via a plural URI (`/widgets/`). That's a problem. If that's just a typo, it would help to know what error you're seeing when you "run into trouble".

**UPDATE:**

> Yes that was a typo. I corrected it. The error that appears for widget/links/ is: Error: WidgetController could not be found. It appears my index/default route is the main problem.

Given that information, it appears that CakePHP thinks that `widget` is your controller. Cake processes routes top down and finds the first one that matches. Ensure that you don't have a route *above* this one that looks something like `/:controller/...` or any other route above this one that starts with a variable.

Comment: Yes that was a typo. I corrected it.

The error that appears for widget/links/ is: Error: WidgetController could not be found.

It appears my index/default route is the main problem.

Comment: I don't have any other routes than the default page routes. Please keep in mind this is only for the index action when access from `/widget/controller_name`. You are right in that it assumes widget is the controller and is trying to use controller_name as the action. 

Clearly that is not the desired behavior. I am tempted to add a `Router::connect('/widget/:controller/', array('action' => 'index'));`

Comment: Then the presence of the trailing slash (/) in your routing statement may be the problem (as before, judging by the URI/routing combination in your comment). Routing can be pretty picky. You may have to provide 2 routes in order to handle both conditions.

Comment: I ultimately had to name the routes as mine was too vague. It the end it looked something like this `Router::connect('/widget/links/:action/*', array('controller' => 'links', 'action' => 'index'));`